# How to copy data after login ssh in bash shell

Tags: ssh, copy, scp

I want to copy data after login ssh already.
But When login already it can't process scp command.

This is my bash file:
copy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
   sshpass -p 123qwe ssh root@192.168.1.14
   scp /home/abc/Documents/backup.tar.gz  root@192.168.1.14:~/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.It should be:

```
sshpass -p '123qwe' scp /home/abc/Documents/backup.tar.gz  root@192.168.1.14:~/Desktop/
```